# Calculating and storing SUM of a column in another table

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, insert, sum

i have table due_list with

```
id , userid , mobno , rs , network , date_posted , time_posted
```

i want to select sum(rs) from due_list  where group by userid 
into another table

```
insert into users(userid,rs,mobno,netwrok) select userid,mobno,network sum('rs') form due_list groub by userid
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Once you fix the syntax errors in the Insert statement (form => from, groub => group), and put the column names in the same order in the Select, is anything still broken? Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 0):

2 errors.

first: you must use BACKTICKS for fieldnames

second: the keyword is group not groub anf FROM not FORM

```
INSERT INTO users (userid,rs,mobno,netwrok)
  SELECT userid,mobno,network sum(`rs`)
  FROM due_list group by userid;
```

Comment: there is little change in my sql  version
INSERT INTO users (userid,rs,mobno,netwrok)
  SELECT userid,mobno,network 'sum(`rs`)
  FROM due_list group by userid' 

single qoutation mark front of  ' sum and after grou by userid ' 
still showing error #1054 - Unknown column 'userid' in 'field list'

Comment: and  2nd error you mentioned is my mistake while typing here thanx for info